# Are the transactions between two accounts have to go through a contract?

Tags: transactions, accounts

Are all the transactions in ethereum have a relation to a contract (its to or from field is a contract). When two accounts want to transfer something between them, do they have to speak through a contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question:** When two accounts want to transfer something between them, do they have to speak through a contract?

There are two types of accounts. From the White Paper (under [Ethereum Accounts](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#ethereum-accounts)):

> In general, there are two types of accounts: externally owned
>   accounts, controlled by private keys, and contract accounts,
>   controlled by their contract code.

You could consider externally owned accounts (EOAs) to be normal, wallet accounts controlled by a user.

Transactions between two normal EOAs don't involve a contract.

Comment: what sort of transactions are between two EOA accounts? exchanging ether?

Comment: Yes, correct. Just the exchange of ether. At a high level, similar to how two bitcoin accounts would transact.